# Run view query in Symfony/propel

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I've an existing project in Symfony 1.4/Propel 1.4

For database optimization purpose, I created a view of few tables. The function/ view query are as follow:

```
create function getPlayer() returns INTEGER DETERMINISTIC NO SQL return @getPlayer;

create view getPlay as
SELECT
    CASE WHEN play.hiderid = getPlayer() THEN play.seekerid ELSE play.hiderid END AS opponent, play . * 
    FROM odd_play play, odd_match mat
    WHERE (seekerid = getPlayer() OR hiderid = getPlayer())
    AND play.id = mat.latestplay;
```

After creating above view, I can write following simple SQL query to get required data effectively.

```
select play.*
from (select @getPlayer:=1 p) p, getPlay play;
```

Now the problem is that, how to write this query in Symfony/Propel 1.4. Can someone please suggest how to write that query in propel 1.4?

**Edit after J0K comments**

I'm trying following

```
class GetplayPeer extends BaseGetplayPeer {
    static public function getOpponents($player){
        $con = Propel::getConnection();
        $sql = "select play.* from (select @getPlayer:=:player p) ply, getPlay play;";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":player",&$player,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $rs = $stmt->execute();
        //$opponents = GetplayPeer::populateObjects($rs);
        echo "opponents=<pre>";print_r($rs);exit;
    }
} // GetplayPeer
```

I'm getting `1` as output, which is not expected output.

Comment: Do you need to hydrate objects after this query? Or just the plain resul is ok?

Comment: @j0k after `symfony propel:build-model` I got classes for view `getPlay` too. So objects of Getplay will be the best solution but as of now, anything will work for me as I'm badly stuck.

Comment: I suggest you to go on raw sql, check this [blog post](http://stereointeractive.com/blog/2007/06/12/propel-queries-using-custom-sql-peer-classes-and-criterion-objects/) (the first method)

Comment: Thanks J0k, I guess that is going to work for me. Let me first make it workable and will try further about effective optimization method.

Comment: Hi @j0k Are you sure its for propel 1.4. `$con->createStatement()` is not working for me. Getting continuous error. Also my IDE (Netbeans) is not showing any such method in auto complete.

Comment: You're right, take a look a the [official doc](http://www.propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#overview) 2nd & 3rd black bloc. Then, I don't think `populateObjects` will be available, give a try.

Comment: @j0k I edited the code I'm trying but getting regular error. I've running code with inner joins in propel. Just trying that to check if it get the data faster (optimization purpose). What do you suggest, should I continue trying this or leave it here only.

Comment: after `execute`, you should fetch data `$result = $stmt->fetchAll();` in fact, you're just using [plain PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetchall.php) :)